# How to order a node's taxonomy terms hierarchically?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, nodes

Are the terms in a node's taxonomy array ordered hierarchically by default?

If not, what is the most efficient way to do so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No they are not ordered hierarchically by default...

In order to do it yourself you could take a look at the following functions: [taxonomy_get_parents()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--taxonomy--taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_get_parents/6) and [taxonomy_get_children()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--taxonomy--taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_get_children/6).

Here is a great article with nice examples: http://davidherron.com/content/improving-navigability-drupal-taxonomy-hierarchies